# theme individual block

Tags: theming

I looked over the theme suggestion but when tried with dummy text, the block doesn't show any dummy text.

on view source, it showed "id=block-menu-menu-top-menu-navigation"

Tried naming block--top-menu-navigation.tpl.php and block--menu-menu-top-menu-navigation.tpl.php but dummy text still doesn't show up.

Perhaps my naming the files is wrong?

Comment: Do you have a block.tpl.php file in your theme directory? I believe you need that as a base. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935477/how-to-theme-a-menu-block-in-drupal

Comment: what theme?, what version of Drupal? and what does the file look like? are you sure css isn't interfering with the display? are permissions correct for the block?

Comment: Drupal version 6 or 7?

Comment: All are Drupal 7. It is under subtheme so I need to to add bootstrap class to block so that it would be responsive.

Comment: Since all you're doing is adding a class, use this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/block_class

Comment: @Webdrips yes! thats better instead of having to do separate templates for blocks. thanks lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template file you have to create should be

**block--menu--menu-top-menu-navigation.tpl.php**

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To know if your tpl file is valid, you can use [Theme Developer](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module to aid you on what available tpl files you can use for a specific Drupal component. Check it out :)